# How to protect or open protected excel file using SSIS

Tags: sql, .net, excel, powershell, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package. Extract data from database, load into an .xls file and then email to users using sp_send_dbmail task. I have few different reports I do this task for. Now the issue is that I need to add password to those files before sending to users. I can do this in two ways: password protect the template manually and load the file in SSIS OR load and password protect the file (both) in SSIS. SSIS has limitations where it cannot open protected file neither has any way to protect the file as a task. Here are the few ways I have research I can do this:

1. Excel Interop via Script Task: Upon a lot of research, I found its not the best practice as it causes a lot of server issues and requires licensing so i dropped this idea.
2. OpenXML via Script Task: It only works with .xlsx but I have .xls file and I can only use .xls
3. Excel Macros: I have created a Macro which perfectly protects a file but the issue arises on how to execute this. Upon research found out it can be executed using Interop.
4. Write a batch file that will execute Excel Macros: I haven't really found a solution on how to run them using batch file (if it is even possible)
5. Use PowerShell to protect the file and then execute them through Execute Process task in SSIS. I am not familiar with PowerShell but I have researching and saw it is possible.

I have done A LOT of research on it and I am unable to find a right solution. My knowledge is very limited to SQL. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Depending on how complicated the macro is, I would convert it to VBScript and run a VBScript but you can achieve the same thing with Powershell. But you must have excel installed on the server. You should first confirm whether or not this is an issue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid in order to convert and work with excel file in VB I need to use Excel Interop. The reason macro works without interop is because it is part of Excel itself and doesn't need interop to communicate. I do have Excel installed on server but it is an old one so only .xls can work. We are not going to update excel right now because we have a lot of process running using excel and we would have to modify all of them. PowerShell is what I have been looking into but there aren't much information on it or examples on how to approach this.

Comment: You only need excel interop if you are calling COM from .net. VBScript is not .net so you won't need it in this case.

Comment: Here is some VBScript to add a pwd. Get this working then call it from SSIS. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/07/how-can-i-password-protect-an-excel-spreadsheet/

Comment: Thanks! Good information but SSIS script task only writes c#.net and VB.net

Comment: You use an execute process task to run CScript.exe. Convoluted but it should work.

Comment: If you are interested in avoiding the interop altogether, then convert your excel macro to VBS, then run the VBS file in an execute process task in SSIS. In the execute process task, set _Executable_ to `CScript.EXE` and set _Arguments_ to the path to your VBScript file, i.e. `C:\MyScripts\TheScript.VBS` if you want to pursue this solution please indicate and I'll help further.

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid but looked like VB wasn't working well for me. Due to my lack of knowledge, I was very confused on how to convert Macros to VBS especially because I don't even have visual basic on my computer - only visual studio. So I kept searching on PowerShell. I have written a script in PoSh that locks a file. I am going to use that script and call it in my SSIS package through execute process task. Fingers crossed, I am hoping it will work for me. I appreciate your help!

Comment: OK Good luck (I did post a link above to a VBScript to do this for you - you just paste it into notepad - you don't need any editor). Powershell is a more 'modern' solution anyway. You're better off learning Powershell than VBScript. They all do the same thing: access Excel COM automation (sometimes via Interop) to manipulate the file. Make sure you unit test the powershell (run it directly) and confirm it works before putting it in SSIS. Don't stick it all together in one lump and expect it to work straightaway. Also make sure that you get all the paths correct (as seen by the SQL Server)

Comment: Great, thanks! so far so good, it all worked just having some issue on server side. Trying to resolve! Since, I used execute task for PoSh script, I wanted to play around with VB as well. I wanted to ask you how I would do that with VB not being installed? For example, how can I get a .exe file for VB. I created a package with VB script just to see if it works. I copied the script you provided into a notepad and saved it as .vbs. That takes care of the argument part in the package but how about executable (.exe) file?

Comment: VBScript is not compiled to a .exe. The .VBS file is enough. Just like powershell where all you need is the .ps1 file. When you want to run a VBScript file you actually run cscript.exe which is already installed and pass the .vbs file to it as an argument.

Comment: To unit test the VBScript you can just double click the .vbs file and it will run.

Comment: Oh is that so? because when I searched how to run the PoSh script through SSIS, all of them had used powershell.exe file!
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: I just created a vbs script and it doesn't run. Use the code provided. It gives an error "invalid character" ahh, oh well! Nice to know I can just scripts without vbs being installed. Thanks for good information!

Comment: Yes. VBScript uses cscript.exe rather than powershell.exe

Comment: Oh, the invalid character thing is probably because the code on that site is in a bad font. It uses weird characters for a double quote. In your code replace all double quote characters with the correct double quote "

Comment: nicee!!! it ran :)

Answer (score 2):

Load the file normally then lock it using a powershell script or a macro (not sure if this is possible). Locking and unlocking are external to SSIS, so its best handled by some sort of scripting language such as powershell. Read this

[Lock Unlock excel files using PS script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/65f3b11f-afcd-40e1-80cf-ab63f4ae14ea/powershell-how-to-lock-a-xls-file?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Thanks, I have mentioned above that I wrote an excel Macro and it worked fine. I just don't know how to execute Macros in SSIS. I also talked about PowerShell. I am also not familiar with how to execute or create a PowerShell file. Is it a text file?

Comment: Not possible to run a macro in SSIS. Never seen that happening since you specifically need to invoke it. On the other hand, I think it maybe helpful to invoke it from execute process task and explore the option of running the macro as an argument to the process task.

Comment: powershell is a script that ends with extension .ps. If you explore it, it will be very helpful to solve a lot of issues with excel that are out of realm of SSIS.

Comment: thanks! I will look more into PowerShell. And I already tried running macros using execute process task but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SSIS ***Script task***. And you needed to add **Microsoft excel** reference like below image.

*Try Add Reference -> COM -> Type Libraries -> 'Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library'.*
[image]

**Use below code for protect excel file.**

```
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    
public void Main()
        {

            // TODO: Add your code here
            

            String excelFile = "D:\\GILEAD\\Spool\\UpdatedFile\\test.xlsx";
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@excelFile);

            workbook.Password = "Shahidul";
          
            //Save the workbook and close it

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            app.Application.Quit();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```